# add a button(tag) in TextView

Tags: swift, button, textview

I want to let user can tag some friend in the textfield and let the tag can be delete by pressing "X". I check other articles but they are teaching how to add a button in the textView's bottom (fixed position). I want to let user can add the tag in textView anywhere they want to add the tag. If this effect can be completed by adding button in the text view? or which way can do this trick by using textView (using `UIBezierPath` or something else)?

Demo screenshot:

[image: Demo screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a complicated way to do this, but I would recommend creating a collection view above/below or even on top of the textfield and populate that after a user adds a friend. Then use didSelectCellAt to handle deleting a cell from the collectionview when a user clicks it.

I know is isn't the exact answer, but it may be an easy workaround. Goodluck!

Comment: for this case I want to let user know the message that their friend actually received. So it is better to put a different style notation in the  textview. Thanks for your comment.